# wpa_gui no adapters

Tags: wifi

So this seems to be different than the other issues I have seen related to wpa_gui if I open it from the shortcut no adapters but if I launch it via sudo wpa_gui it will work fine. What do I need to change to make it run as root from the menu?

Comment: Hi and welcome to raspberrypi.SE. I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question at all. What is it you want to achieve? What did you try? What failed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have the following lines in your wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
# needed for wpa_gui to work 
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev 
# needed to allow wpa_gui to alter the configuration 
update_config=1
```

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
  GNU nano 2.2.6    File: /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

Comment: mine matches up

Comment: What is the output of `groups pi` (assuming you are using the `pi` user as your normal account) ... does it include `netdev` ?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ groups pi
pi : pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users netdev input indiecity spi gpio